# Expected Output not coming while comparing 2 numbers in linux

Tags: linux, bash

[image]
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---comparing-numbers

**HackerRank Problem:Comparing Numbers**

> I am writing a simple problem in linux that says Given two integers, X and Y, identify whether X is greater than Y or X is less than Y or X is equal to Y:

Below is my Code:

```
read x y

if ((x>y)); then  
echo "x is greater than y"; 
elif ((x==y)); then  
echo "x is equal to y"; 
else  
echo "x is less than y"; 
fi;
```

But I am not getting correct answer in some of the Shells:
I don't know how to correct and why isn't not working in some of the bash shells.

> Can anyone guide me Why and How to correct this?
>   Thanx in advance.

Comment: "Some of the Shells"  which shells?  `csh` (c-shell) for example uses a totally different syntax to `sh` and `bash`.

Comment: _"...and why isn't not working in some of the bash shells."_  Which bash shells would those be?

Comment: I just noticed the `read x y` in your post.  Should that be part of your code?  If so, should it not be `read a b`?

Comment: @cdarke Edited Sorry for confusion.I am using bash shell and in the mac and the hackerRank two uses the same shell but I don't know why it is not showing

Comment: The code you now supply works fine for me on bash 3.2, bash 4, and sh, all on mac.  Apart from being very poorly formatted (no whitespace, no indentation), I can't see anything wrong with it - it should work.  When it fails, run the script with `xtrace` on, the simplest way to do that is to : `bash -x script-name`.  That will show each line expanded as it is run, and should help indicate what is going on.

Comment: @cdarke I have edited Where it shows error to me and the below code of Deo works fine but why

Comment: I can't copy your image to try your exact code, paste the code into your question if you want me to do that.  This is a question you really have to ask of HackerRank, it could be that it doesn't like the style you use, or maybe you should not include the `read`.

Comment: read x y

if ((x>y)); then  
echo "x is greater than y"; 
elif ((x==y)); then  
echo "x is equal to y"; 
else  
echo "x is less than y"; 
fi;

Comment: Its not working because you have read x y. Write read x read y in separate lines and your code will work on hacker rank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
If x and y are variables, why a and b ? Also even if you declare read a b, you need to add $a,$b inside if. I don't think it would work in any shell.

```
read x
read y

if (($x>$y)); then  
echo "x is greater than y"; 
elif (($x==$y)); then  
echo "x is equal to y"; 
else  
echo "x is less than y"; 
fi;
```

Comment: Thankx for the code but why my code doesn't work fine in the hacker rank bash shell.

Comment: Its not working because you have read x y. Write read x read y in separate lines and your code will work on hacker rank.

Comment: Thank you why there shell doesn't read 2 inputs in same line?

Comment: check their input statement. If it says "two lines" specifically, its precondition to input integers in two lines. As far as I know, inputs are given in separate lines in hacker rank problems